# Using Vbscript/PowerShell How to check if an AD user account has permissions to modify AD group membership?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a custom Operating System deployment solution (OSD Upgrade) which as part of the process has to first modify a few associated AD group memberships using the user account of the person who triggers the OSD (trigger is done in the domain-joined Full OS using an AD account).

I need to programmatically check (using preferably Vbscript or even PowerShell) if that user has the necessary permissions to modify the group first. If not, I would like to display a message and terminate the OSD process.

Could you please help? By the way, there is no AD PowerShell module on the host so it has to be ADSI route.

Steve

Comment: You can check if the user has the permissions to to something by *doing it*. This either works, or it fails with an "access denied" error, in which case you can display a message and terminate the OSD process. This approach is much simpler, cleaner and more reliable than trying to figure out if you have a permission.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. I have used the try catch in Powershell to capture the access denied now. It is working as expected. I was wondering if there was any other simpler way but I agree checking ACL is another nightmare. This is much simpler. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not only simpler, it's also the "best practice" approach for literally all access-controlled operations. The code that checks the ACL is part of the operating system, and your unified API (so to speak) to this built-in functionality is "doing the thing you were about to do, and catching the error". Trying to duplicate the code that checks ACLs is cumbersome, error-prone and superfluous.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.